# How Can I Create a Full Screen Carousel/Slide Show?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am a beginner in web designing. I am trying to create a full screen carousel/slide show for a specific section of a web page.

More specifically, I have a carousel like this:
https://codepen.io/john9929/pen/aEjBqZ

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph781/f/styles/tiled_homepage_blog/public/bigstock-Los-Angeles-5909078.jpg?itok=Pu2dewLz" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
          <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Chicago_skyline%2C_viewed_from_John_Hancock_Center.jpg/500px-Chicago_skyline%2C_viewed_from_John_Hancock_Center.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
          <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to transform it into this: 
https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-carousel/

How can I do it?

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 3 in your example but tagged this question with Bootstrap 4. What gives?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Add the bootstrap-3 tag. Otherwise no one will find your question.

Comment: I have added the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set width to 100% and you can even set fixed height for consistency.

```
.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
}
```

---

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
 .carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
  max-height:340px;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
  max-height:720px;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 992px) { 
   .carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
  }
  .carousel-inner{
    max-height:580px;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
      max-height:700px;

  }
    .carousel-inner{
    max-height:700px;
  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">


  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph781/f/styles/tiled_homepage_blog/public/bigstock-Los-Angeles-5909078.jpg?itok=Pu2dewLz" alt="LA" width="1200" height="700">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
          <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg" alt="New York" width="1200" height="700">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
          <p>Thank you, New York - A night we won't forget.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Chicago_skyline%2C_viewed_from_John_Hancock_Center.jpg/500px-Chicago_skyline%2C_viewed_from_John_Hancock_Center.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1200" height="700">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago!!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The width is now 100%. However, I am facing an issue with the height. When I included "height: 80%;" in .carousel-inner img, nothing happens. How can I reduce the height of the images?

Comment: @john, it's supposed to be done using Media query. Using % will not be useful as it works only when it's referenced to something. I have updated the answer please check, and will add a brief explanation soon.